# Python Randint function w/ repetition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with a simple function

```
def D6_roll():
    from random import randint
    return randint(1, 6)
```

I wanted to see the distribution of results after 1, 10, & 10,000 rolls, so I built this out

```
def D6_roll():
    from random import randint
    if randint(1, 6) == 1:
        return "1"
    elif randint(1, 6) == 2:
        return "2"
    elif randint(1, 6) == 3:
        return "3"
    elif randint(1, 6) == 4:
        return "4"
    elif randint(1, 6) == 5:
        return "5"
    else:
        return "6"

num_rolls = int(input("Please input roll sample size: "))
tally1 = 0
tally2 = 0
tally3 = 0
tally4 = 0
tally5 = 0
tally6 = 0
total = 0

for trial in range(num_rolls):
    total = total + int(D6_roll())
    
    if D6_roll() == "1":
        tally1 = tally1 + 1

    elif D6_roll() == "2":
        tally2 = tally2 + 1

    elif D6_roll() == "3":
        tally3 = tally3 + 1

    elif D6_roll() == "4":
        tally4 = tally4 + 1
        
    elif D6_roll() == "5":
        tally5 = tally5 + 1
        
    else:
        tally6 = tally6 + 1

print(f"1 was rolled {tally1}x")
print(f"2 was rolled {tally2}x")
print(f"3 was rolled {tally3}x")
print(f"4 was rolled {tally4}x")
print(f"5 was rolled {tally5}x")
print(f"6 was rolled {tally6}x")
```

Now here's where things get weird and why I've come seeking help...

If you look at

```
   for trial in range(num_rolls):
        total = total + int(D6_roll())
```

And then compare it to this line

```
sum_of_rolls = (1 * tally1) + (2 * tally2) + (3 * tally3) + (4 * tally4) + (5 * tally5) + (6 * tally6)
```

Shouldn't the total = sum_of_rolls? If not, why? I'm at a loss trying to explain my observed results. To anyone who made it this far, thank you in advance for helping a coding newb!

full code at https://github.com/thesageRR3/Python/blob/main/D6_Roll.py

Comment: You need to save the value of `D6_roll()` to a variable, and then compare that variable to '1', '2', etc.  As the code is written, you're rolling for each comparison.

Comment: You have the same problem with `d6_roll()`.  You need to call randint **once** and then look at the result.  As the code is currently written, you're going to get way to many 6s just because that's the default case.  You could also just return `str(randint(1, 6))`.

Comment: To emphasize the issue with `D6_roll` in your second snippet, assuming a uniform distribution for `randint`, you generate `"1"` with probability 1/6, `"2"` with probability (5/6)*(1/6), `"3"` with probability `(5/6)*(5/6)*(1/6)`, etc. You're simulating an (almost) [geometrically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) distributed die, not a uniform one.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that `D6_roll()` is producing a new random integer on each roll, so the `D6_roll()` summed into total does not match the one that you added into your tally. As a suggestion, use a dictionary:

```
from random import randint
num_rolls = 100
result = {i : 0 for i in range(1, 7)}
total = 0
for trial in range(num_rolls):
    roll = randint(1, 6)
    total += roll
    result[roll] += 1
print(total, sum(key * value for key, value in result.items()))
```

Notice here that `roll` is stored and referenced both by `total` and `result`, rather than calling `randint(1, 6)` in both places, which has the potential for the two values to be different.

Comment: Goes without saying that I need to refine my understanding of dictionaries in Python, as from what I can see your approach significantly cuts down on the bloat of what I submitted. 

Thanks for taking the time out to show me a better way!

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call D6_roll() as a condition you get a new roll. If you want to get only one roll per cycle, you should store the result in a variable and then use that variable, something like:

```
for trial in range(num_rolls):
    roll = int(D6_roll())
    total = total + roll
    if roll == 1:
        tally1 = tally1 + 1
    elif roll == 2:
        tally2 = tally2 + 1
...
```

Comment: Some suggestions regarding your code:
- As you want to get a random integer number between 1 and 6, I would recommend just using `randint(1, 6)` directly
- I don't understand why you change the type of the outputs so many times, from integer to string to integer; Try to avoid doing that kind of thing unless its strictly necessary, to avoid confusion
- Try to avoid unnecessary conditionals, like in your second `D6_roll()` definition, if you wanted the output to be a string of the `randint` output, you could just `return str(randint(1, 6))` instead

Comment: Your reply shows where I somehow skipped a step in coding the initial function. Just one of a few mistakes I'm now seeing after digesting everyone's replies on here. Much obliged for helping me to see the forest through the trees!

Answer (score 0):

There is a big problem with the code you've implemented - namely, you are calling the `random.randint` function multiple times within `D6_roll`, and then you are calling `D6_roll` multiple times in your for loop. It is important that you only roll the dice one time in your code, otherwise it will give you unanticipated results.

To fix this, the first step is to fix `D6_roll`:

```
def D6_roll():
    from random import randint
    roll = randint(1, 6)
    return str(roll)
```

This will roll the dice a single time and return the result as a string.

The second step is to change inside the for loop:

```
for trial in range(num_rolls):
    roll = D6_roll()
    total += int(roll)

    if roll == "1":
        tally1 += 1
    elif roll == "2":
        tally2 += 1
    ...
```

This will roll the dice *exactly once* then use it to perform your calculations. After you fix these two things, your `sum_of_rolls` function should equal `total`.

Comment: This was the simple and elegant reply I was looking for, thank you for taking the time to write this! I see what I did wrong, and I hope I can apply what you've shown me here to my future endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

def D6_roll():
    return randint(1, 6)

def roll(n = 10):
    d = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0}
    for i in range(n):
        d[D6_roll()] += 1
    return d

roll(100)
Out[1]: {1: 23, 2: 18, 3: 13, 4: 19, 5: 11, 6: 16}

roll(1000)
Out[2]: {1: 153, 2: 167, 3: 161, 4: 166, 5: 172, 6: 181}

roll(10000)
Out[3]: {1: 1682, 2: 1705, 3: 1677, 4: 1602, 5: 1717, 6: 1617}
```

You can check whether the number of rolls are the same: ie

```
sum(roll(20).values())
Out[5]: 20  ## Gives you 20 as expected
```

Comment: I'm still trying to nail down my understanding of dictionaries, but I know enough to appreciate how this could streamline my code. I'll just have to bookmark this reply for now and refer to it later.

Thanks for replying and showing me something new!

Comment: @JayRivs if this answers your question,you could accept it as the answer in order to close the question